# Process login (single sign on) via javascript

Tags: javascript

at the moment, i'm using a freelancer to buid single sign on (login integration) with a web app.

My Freelancer use javascript to process and transfer data, i'm bit worried since javascript is a client side scripting. At the moment, i already use SSL. some 'transaction' he build with javascript:
- get data via javascript on background (he sent password and username via url param)
- send username and password between function in the javascript

Would like to your opinion, is it safe ? does SSL protect data that transmitted via javascript ?

just a bit worried

Comment: SSL encrypts information sent via HTTP. Javascript is irrelevant.

Comment: SSL protects the entire contents of any packets sent across the socket, this includes all header information which is where the URL is. SSL isn't 100% safe of course, but the URL parameters are no less safe than any of the rest of the data transferred.

Comment: @User031881: Highly vulnerable against what?

Comment: the script request URL in background by sending password and username, like https://localhost/auth.php?s=123123123&u=mylogin&p=mypassword..... doesn't seem right, what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

The method it is sent is not so relevant. I imagine you are doing it via AJAX, right? Only make sure to use POST method, never GET Method.